# Looking for an algorithm to count the number of possible patterns

Tags: python, r, algorithm, matlab, matrix

I need your help in constructing an algorithm to solve the following problem:

`A 5x5 table can be filled with the values ​​0 and 1 so that each line and each column of the table consists of exactly two ones and three zeros. How many solutions exist?`

If you want to provide some code, you can freely use your preferred language. I mostly use R, Matlab and Python.

I tried to convert the table into a vector:

```
unique(perms([ones(1,10),zeros(1,15)]), 'rows')
```

Then, for each row, I would form the 5x5 table and check if all row sums and col sums equal 2. But the above command generated the error: `??? Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.`

Comment: could you describe what you have tried?

Comment: Such a small table: Stop thinking, make a brute forth approach.

Comment: @MrSmith42 - Exactly. Of course, if this were a 7x7 table, with say 2 ones required in each row and column, the problem with become interesting. As it is, trivial.

Comment: @woodchips: even for 7x7 you can generate all 7*6=42 possible rows with two ones. and than brute force all 42^7 (about 10^11 possibilities).

Comment: @MrSmith42 - actually, there are only 21 distinct sets of rows with 2 ones out of 7. You counted each row twice.

Comment: @woodchips| You are right I forgot that the order of the ones does not matter. 7*6/2=21

Comment: @woodchips: I didn't understand why is it trivial to get 2040 (the correct answer). Could you help a little more?

Comment: @Brani - Even with absolute brute force, there are only 2^25 tables. If you choose more carefully, one can easily reduce the search space to 10^5 tables to search over. Computers have no problem with such small spaces to search.

Comment: Here is a python code that bute forces the matrices with two 1s per row: http://ideone.com/m5iFTB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a python expression that bute forces all the matrices with two 1s per row:

```
from itertools import *
print len(filter(
  lambda candidate: all(imap(
    lambda index: sum(imap(lambda _: _[index], candidate)) == 2,
    xrange(5)
  )),
  product(set(permutations([0,0,0,1,1])), repeat=5)
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Matlab function `perms` for vector `[0 0 0 1 1]`, I think you'll have it then.

Comment: Well, if you choose this approach, then it is unique(perms([0 0 0 1 1]),'rows')

Comment: Yes, thanks for that addition! I don't think the 'rows' is needed, or well...it is pretty trivial either way.

Comment: Yes, 'rows' is needed, as otherwise, the unique call returns simply the vector [0;1].

Comment: That gives one solution. I am interested in counting the number of possible such tables.

Comment: @Fraukje It becomes 2040 (this is the correct answer) but I can't see how.

Comment: So what I would do (and this might not be the best approach), is to calculate (or simulate) how many matrices you can make which hold _rows_ with 3 zeros and 2 ones. Then check by running an algorithm over it that counts the _colums_ for exactly 2 ones how many of these matrices also hold 2 ones.